# On button click run function that add stuff to body

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Sorry for noobish question, i am new to html/javascript.
Lets say i have a from:

```
<form id="pass" >
        <p>
            Password: <input type="password" name="password" >
            Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="User">

            <input type="submit" value="Send" class=btn> <input type="Reset" class=btn>
        </p>
    </form>
```

And when button is pressed. I want to run function in `script.js` file, that for example clear the body.

What is the right way to do it?

Many thanks!

Comment: clear the body or clear the form's value?

Comment: Not so important. Clear the <body> for example.

Comment: include script.js , and onclick="name of function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a code in your form tag as `onsubmit="javascript: function_name();"` example:

```
<form name="name" id="name" onsubmit="javascript: function_name();">
    // your code
</form>
```

Now in your JS, write:

```
<script>
function function_name() {
    alert("hi");
}
</script>
```

Comment: `javascript:function_name();` in an `onsubmit` is misleading; `onsubmit` doesn’t point to a URI, and `javascript:` is acting as a label. Just use `function_name();`, and remember to return a value to cancel as appropriate – or, even better, add a listener dynamically. It looks better and is more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Download, include and use jQuery.

Give the button an `id` (for example, `DoSomething`) in your markup and call it like this:

```
$('#DoSomething').click(function() {
    alert('my button works');
});
```

Comment: Please use the `submit` event of the form.